# Don't scroll ScrollViewer behind image

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a ScrollViewer which is partly covered by an image in my Windows Phone 8 app. Now when you begin scrolling on the image it works just like when begin scrolling outside of the image. But I want to prevent the ScrolLViewer from scrolling when the drag movement starts on the image. The image is a partly transparent png file, but the same behaviour occurs when I replace it with a rectangle.
How can I do this with WP8?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or a xaml? Otherwise, its hard to know/visualize the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to attach event handlers to the Image's MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseLeave, and MouseLeftButtonUp to disable and then re-enable the ScrollViewer's vertical/horizontal scrolling.

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
}

private void Image_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
}

private void Image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I disable scrolling for the ScrollViewer inside of a ListBox?

Comment: For a ListBox, VerticalScrollBarVisibility is an attached property, so you would use ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(listbox, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);